Can you make configuration settings revolving around Terminal settings in vscode?
I generally always make Terminal changes i.e move panel to right etc.  These persist when made in a given workspace but each time I'm open a new one they're lost.
I also tend to make various other Terminal settings that I would like to make global.
Is it possible to do this?
OS: macOS
vscode version: 1.92.1
I can't seem to find any obvious Terminal related settings.

You could start by reviewing VSCode terminal profiles setups here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles#_configuring-profiles
In broad steps, you should create an specific profile for the setup you want to use and then define it as "default profile".
For instance, this profile will predefine the powershell "Custom Init" profile for your terminal in visualstudio Code.
{
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "Custom Init": {
      "path": "pwsh.exe",
      "args": [
         "-noexit",
         "-file",
         "${env:APPDATA}\\PowerShell\\custom-init.ps1"
      ]
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Custom Init"
}

Related to the positioning, that might be actually related to the layout you use on Visual Studio Code. You can gain broader knowledge here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_workspace-settings
there is an additional post here about "restoring panels setup" that might help you "recovering a previous closed setups", and abounds on the panels distributions:
How can I save/restore window layouts in VS Code?
I hope this sets a good base starting point for your custom set up of the editor, happy coding!

why... are you mentioning visual studio?

because it is the subject matter of the question.

it is not.⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Ok, Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are not the same thing, so corrected.that text. Response, anyway, applies to VisualStudio Code.
